# Cannot boot migrated Ubuntu VM on fresh XenServer install

Tags: xen, xenserver

It's been a tough couple of days. My server configuration went crazy after a power outage, and now I'm trying to get my VMs back up and running.

I reinstalled XenServer to a new SSD in the same box. I added my old SSD as a storage repository to my freshly installed instance. I tried to backup the metadata from my old instance, but it had an error when attempting to backup the pool so it looks like I'm not able to restore all of my VMs the automated way (I tried to use the restore option anyway and it didn't work).

I can see all the disks on my new install just fine. I'm able to create new VMs and attach my existing VDIs without much issue for Windows instances. They boot as expected.

However, my Ubuntu VMs (12.04) will not start. They show a black screen, then when I hit *Enter*, they show a black screen with an underscore (cursor, but it's not flashing) in the upper left corner. The performance tab shows 100% CPU usage. They never boot, I cannot ping them (not that the network tab shows an IP address anyway).

One other strange thing to note - this seems to only be broken for instances that were originally created in XenServer. I have one Ubuntu VM that I migrated from VirtualBox, and that one boots just fine. All other "native" VMs fail to boot.

Any ideas? The only other thing to note is that they wouldn't even try to boot at first. When attempting to start any newly created VM, I got the error:

```
The bootloader for this VM returned an error -- did the VM installation succeed?  INVALID_SOURCE
```

In my notes, I have it documented to run this command to get the VM to start:

```
xe vm-param-set uuid=<vm-uuid> HVM-boot-policy=BIOS\ order HVM-boot-params:order=dc
```

This seemed to get me closer, but now I just get the black screen and I'm not sure how to proceed.